# What is the easiest option to stream videos in different resolutions from CloudFlare

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare

Would it be easier to have to convert them to all the needed resolutions, or can cloudflare stream it in lower resolutions automatically?

Answer (score 0):

A quick search turns up this:

> Sites that do streaming content, however, should move their streaming content to a subdomain we don't proxy[,] in their DNS settings.
>
> We have seen sites have performance issues because of the number of connections that streamed content causes when running through the CloudFlare proxy.
>
> https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169706-Can-I-use-CloudFlare-with-a-streaming-music-or-video-site-

Given that they are essentially saying "don't route your streaming request through Cloudflare, because we've received reports that it doesn't scale well if you do," it seems like a reasonable assumption that they do not offer any automated manipulation (transcoding) of your streams... so, yes, you'll have to transcode it yourself.

If there are services that handle conversion to "lower resolutions automatically," they are likely to be the exception, not the norm: transcoding video is a resource-intensive process it has subjective tunable parameters which do not necessarily have "correct" settings or "ideal" settings that are optimal for every stream, and transcoding is a poster child for the tradeoff between speed and quality -- to a significant extent, the more CPU time spent by a transcoding process, the higher the quality of the final result will be for a given bit rate.  Transcoding on-the-fly, on demand, as would be needed by a system like Cloudflare, would be unweildy if not entirely impractical and would likely optimize for speed, not quality.